# restore back up on localDB got Failed(exit code:1)

Tags: postgresql

guys!
I'm trying to restore the backup DB to my local DB, but I got the Failed with exit code :1, there is no error log come up. I'm on Mac OS.
running command is

```
/Volumes/pgAdmin 4/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore --host "127.0.0.1" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "sport_match" --section=pre-data --section=data --section=post-data --create --verbose "/Users/dylan/Downloads/sportmatch_2021"
```

any one have any idea?
thanks in advance!

Comment: You should [edit] the question and add the error message.

Comment: there's no error message. is this because I got error "A non-fatal error occur whilst creating menu shortcuts." when I install postgreSQL?

Comment: No. But if the return code is 1, there has to be an error message.